# Case within Case when combining multiple columns into one

Tags: sql, casting, case

I'm trying to create a query that will take multiple columns in a View and bring it into one column in the query.  The values from each column needs to be separated by '|' (pipe).

I've tried:

1) `(expression1 + '|' + expression2) AS xxxx`, but if one expression has a null value, it makes the results 'null'.

2) `CAST (expression1 as varchar (10)) + '|' + CAST (expression2 as varchar (10)) AS xxxx`, but get the same results.

3) `CASE (expression1 is null) then (' ') else (expression1) +'|' + CASE (expression2 is null) then (' ') else (expression2) END AS xxxx`, but I get a syntax error near the keyword `'AS'.`

Here's the full query using CASE.

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.REG.BUILDING, dbo.REG.CURRENT_STATUS, dbo.REG_CONTACT.LOGIN_ID, dbo.REG.LAST_NAME
, CASE WHEN dbo.View_MYAccess_Period1.CRSGRP1 is null then ' ' else        dbo.View_MYAccess_Period1.CRSGRP1 + ' |' +
  CASE WHEN dbo.View_MYAccess_Period2.CRSGRP2 is null then ' ' else dbo.View_MYAccess_Period2.CRSGRP2
END AS CRSGRP

FROM  dbo.REG_CONTACT RIGHT OUTER JOIN
dbo.REG_STU_CONTACT ON dbo.REG_CONTACT.CONTACT_ID = dbo.REG_STU_CONTACT.CONTACT_ID RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
dbo.REG ON dbo.REG_STU_CONTACT.STUDENT_ID = dbo.REG.STUDENT_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN 
dbo.View_MYAccess_Period1 ON dbo.REG.STUDENT_ID = dbo.View_MYAccess_Period1.STUDENT_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.View_MYAccess_Period2 ON dbo.REG.STUDENT_ID = dbo.View_MYAccess_Period2.STUDENT_ID
```

Any help for this newbie would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Sorry, that would help.  SQLServer 2005.

Answer (score 1):

Use ISNULL function,

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.REG.BUILDING, dbo.REG.CURRENT_STATUS, dbo.REG_CONTACT.LOGIN_ID, dbo.REG.LAST_NAME
, ISNULL(dbo.View_MYAccess_Period1.CRSGRP1,' ') + ' |' +
  ISNULL(dbo.View_MYAccess_Period2.CRSGRP2,' ') CRSGRP

FROM  dbo.REG_CONTACT RIGHT OUTER JOIN
dbo.REG_STU_CONTACT ON dbo.REG_CONTACT.CONTACT_ID = dbo.REG_STU_CONTACT.CONTACT_ID RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
dbo.REG ON dbo.REG_STU_CONTACT.STUDENT_ID = dbo.REG.STUDENT_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN 
dbo.View_MYAccess_Period1 ON dbo.REG.STUDENT_ID = dbo.View_MYAccess_Period1.STUDENT_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.View_MYAccess_Period2 ON dbo.REG.STUDENT_ID = dbo.View_MYAccess_Period2.STUDENT_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

In example 1, you might use the `COALESCE(expression, fallback)` function to force `expression` to return a fallback value if the expression is null. (Then tweak the rest of the logic accordingly.)

In your example 3, you need another `END` keyword:

```
CASE
    (expression1 is null) then (' ')
    ELSE (expression1) +'|' +
        CASE (expression2 is null) then (' ') else (expression2) END
END AS xxxx
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It's good to know multiple ways of doing something.  The COALesce worked, but I'm still getting an error, but this time it's an incorrect syntax near the keywork 'IS'.